# How would I make an iOS popup be delayed by 0.5 seconds?

Tags: xcode

In an app i am making, I press a button, an animation occurs, then a popup appears.
I am currently running them when a single action is called but though that the animation would finish before popping the popup up.

How would I get xcode to delay the popup by 0.5 seconds after being activated?

Comment: [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I use one? (I am very inexperienced)

Comment: I recommend reading through the documentation and/or some tutorials on it, and experimenting with it. It'd be difficult to provide you more details without a more solid foundation to build from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to get my popup to delay. just change the delay value to your liking

```
let delay = 0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay));
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     // enter your popup code here
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "DELAYED POPUP", message: "THIS WORKED NICELY",     preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


})
```